# \textbf \texttt \textit is not working anymore

Tags: fonts, packages, bold, italic, typewriter

I am trying latex for the first time to write an essay for school, in the beginning the \textbf \texttt and \textit worked normaly. But i started to use more and more different packages and copied some of a friend of mine. Now i'm not getting any bold or italic fonds. Are there any packages that can overwrite the bold or italic fonds?

i am using the following packages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %voor accenten op letters ( umlaut bijv.)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %For better font
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{gensymb} %  Generic symbols for both text and math mode
\usepackage{hyperref} % voor het toevoegen van links aan het document
\usepackage{graphicx} % voor plaatjes in het document
\usepackage{tabularx} % Tabulars with adjustable-width columns
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Extensive control of page headers and footers in LaTeX2e
\usepackage{lastpage} % Needed for extra-fancy page numbering
\usepackage{pdfpages} % Include PDF documents in LaTeX
\usepackage{eurosym} %(geen idee of het nodig is) voor het 'euro'-%teken
\usepackage{wrapfig} %  Produces figures which text can flow around
\usepackage{tocloft} %  Control table of contents, figures, etc
\usepackage{textgreek} %voor textomega enzo
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\floatstyle{plain}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim} % for \begin{comment} and \end{comment}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,headheight=.4in,headsep=12pt,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ieee,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{longtable}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{Heijmans}
\fancyhead[R]{S. Kusters}

% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\selectlanguage{dutch}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
% Useful packages
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption, float}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newfloat{chart}{tbhp}{crt}
\title{Stage HTL-DHT: bulk glycerine tulip afdeling}
\author{Gijs van Asten}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{longtable}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{HTL-DHT}
\fancyhead[R]{Dhr G.A.J. van Asten}

%\fontfamily{lmss}

\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{sfdefault}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Well it is easy for you to find the culprit: simply comment one by one the lines in your preamble until the fonts work again.

Comment: If you're writing an essay for school I'm pretty sure that you don't need `comment`, `fullpage`, `lipsum`, `textcomp`, `enumerate` (which is incompatible with `enumitem` that you load as well), `gensymb`, `tabularx`, `lastpage`, `pdfpages`, `eurosym` (unless you actually need the euro symbol), `wrapfig`, `tocloft`, `textgreek`, `listings`, `parskip`, `adjustbox`, `paralist`, `subfiles`, `subcaption`, `verbatim`, `tablefootnote`, `emptypage`, `ulem` (underlining is typographically bad outside of single symbols in math), etc. I suggest you clean up your preamble.

Comment: BTW: You are loading some packages more than once. This is not generally a mistake, but it can easily lead to a mistake, because it is somehow confusing. And package `hyperref` should be loaded as late as possible. In general, a package should only be loaded after `hyperref` if this is explicitly documented in the package's manual or the `hyperref` manual.

Comment: Better yet: I suggest starting with an empty preamble and adding stuff only if you need it. This is a common mistake by beginners, starting with an overfull preamble they got from some friend/colleague without understanding what the things do. They don't mean to do harm, but often they do.

Comment: Apart from the advice in the above comments which I totally agree with, I think the culprit here is `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{sfdefault}` which should probably rather be `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` (with a backslash added to the second argument).

Comment: @JasperHabicht just to be clear: I didn't wrote about removing packages but about removing *lines*. And I wished people wouldn't jump in so fast but give new users a chance to learn to debug a document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sure, however, I think that everybody has a different approach to learning. In this case, I decided to give an answer with a reduced MWE that exhibits the error and gives some overall advice, which I hope is also helpful to learn how to approach problems in future projects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should really consider cleaning up your preamble and only load those packages that you really need. It is not a problem per se to load packages that are not being used, but loading many packages quickly lead to confusion and eventually errors may occur.

In your case, however, the problem you are encountering is not being generated by any specific package. Rather the very last line of your preamble has an error and this is completely unrelated to any of the loaded packages. A minimal (non-)working example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\textit{this should be italic}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

The relevant line is missing a backslash in the second argument: It should be `\sfdefault` and not just `sfdefault`. The following should work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\textit{this should be italic}
\end{document}
```

[image]